# Converting array variable back to string for ajax post

Tags: javascript, ajax

Someone helped me with this yesterday but it's now messed up how I send a string query to my endpoint in the AJAX call.

Functionally, this script works but by converting `searchResult` to an array, it screwed up my ajax call and what I send as a string query to an endpoint.

How can I modify this to make sure it sends `searchResult` as a string again to my ajax?

```
$('#productInput').on('input', function () {
  let _this = $(this);
  let foundOption;
  let searchResult = [];
  let optSelector = `option[value='${_this.val()}']`;
  if (_this.val() === '') {
    return;
  } else if ((foundOption = $('#returnedProducts').find(optSelector)).length) {
    $("#groupName").val(searchResult[$(foundOption).attr('srindex')]._source);
    $("#groupNum").val(searchResult[$(foundOption).attr('srindex')]._source);
  } else {
    $.ajax({ url: '/account/autocomplete', 
      data: {
        search_result: searchResult
      },
      "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
      type: "POST", 
      success: function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        let searchResult = response.hits.hits;
        console.log(searchResult);
        $("#returnedProducts").empty();

        for(let i = 0; i < response.hits.hits.length; i++) {
          $("#returnedProducts").append("<option value=" + searchResult[i]._source.category + ">" + searchResult[i]._source.category + "</option>");


        }
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: What is `searchResult` at the moment?

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman Originally I was doing this in the line above my ajax call ```const searchResult = $(this).val(); ``` and it worked perfectly

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify ?

Comment: You may either use `JSON.stringify` or if it's an array, then `searchResult.join()` or something...

Comment: So, originally I was sending the input value to the enpoint as a string query, so you say I should make a new variable that is a stringify of searchResult?

Comment: @Whisou138 both `JSON.stringify` and `string.join()` yield strings. So you will still send a string to the API

Comment: @JulienLachal that's what I thought but I put this in my ajax data ```search_result: JSON.stringify(searchResult)``` and it didn't work

Comment: Seems to be empty array to begin with at the time you make the ajax request. Not at all clear what you need to accomplish here

Comment: I'm just trying to pass input value, on each keystroke, as the data in the ajax post @charlietfl . Someone helped me yesterday on a separate issue which works for a dummy object but it created this issue with ajax. I originally had searchResult as a const

Comment: So why did you change from sending the input value? the array logic at top really doesn't make sense. That array is empty before the request populates it

Comment: I didn't change that, and that's what I'm trying to make sense of. The other user helped with my logic for appending the <object> on click function, but by doing this he doesn't see how to fix what he did with the starting logic. So this would be fine with everything after the POST but I need to pass the input value to the ajax data as a string to begin with

Comment: I may have fixed it by removing the array completely and adding the const back in but I'm not sure yet